# Java: nested class function?

Tags: java, function, object, package

ob is an instance of an object.

If I call the function getname it returns the class type

ob.getClass().getName()

My doubt is, how come getclass and getname are 2 functions, are they some how nested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they aren't. `getClass` will return to you a [`Class` object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html). The `Class` object contains a method called [`getName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29). The code you posted is similar to:

```
 Class cls = ob.getClass();
 String name = cls.getName();
```

Answer (score 1):

They are not actually nested. the function getClass is returning an object that has a function named getName.
here is an example....

```
class Ob
{
    public NewObject FirstFunction()
    {

    }
}


class NewObject
{
    public void SecondFunction()
    {

    }
}
```

In a case like this you can do something like ob.FirstFunction().SecondFunction(); if we assume that ob is an object of Ob. Hope this makes clear.

Comment: Specifically, `getClass` is returning a [`Class` object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html). Your example is misleading, `getClass` is `final` and so we know for certain what it returns.

Comment: For the example of getClass, I agree with you... I have just given example of how such functions can be grouped together. I will do necessary edit.

Comment: :-) While you're doing that, you may want to fix the syntax errors (`class` must be in lower case).